# Jade/PUG JSON interpolation

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug, pugjs

First of all let me tell you that I'm not using Express but only Pug (formerly know as Jade).

I read a JSON object from an external file. Inside the object, one of the keys has a string value that looks like this:

`This is #[strong cool]`

Jade outputs it exactly as that but I'd wish to have the interpolation work for the read string. Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022780/5639288

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `This is #{strong cool}`. [Note the curly brackets.](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/)

And in case you miss it in the docs, [Pug changed how interpolation works for attributes](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2305)

It used to be

```
a(href="#{link}")
a(href='before#{link}after')
```

but now you should use

```
a(href=link)
a(href=`before${link}after\`)
a(href='before' + link + 'after')
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. The issue comes with the string being interpreted exactely as a string as it's read from the json. It needs a parsing method. I do know about interpolations in attributes. Thanks!

Comment: How are you pulling your data in? I use  `locals: {
                'clients': JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('./markup/data/clients.json', { encoding: 'utf8' }) )` in my gulp task. Or maybe you mean something like `This is strong#{JSON.stringify(cool)}`?

Comment: Hey Jason, I'm pulling data the same way you're doing it. But imagine in your ./markup/data/clients.json you have the following: `{ "title": "This is #[strong cool]" }`. Outputting it in a heading tag would go like this: `h2=jsonobj.title`. I want it to output exactly this: `<h2>This is <strong>cool</strong></h2>`. In pug, without grabbing the string, you would do it like this: `h2 This is #[strong cool]` and please note that interpolation operators are right with the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

My dummy solution for this was to use
`This is <strong>cool</strong>`

This works.

Comment: @JoãoSaro Nope, it's just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "interpolation".

It means that "messages()" is escaped, fx if you have following code:

`var randomText = <p>this is a text</p>`

p= randomText
which would normally, unescaped, produce just what the actual string is:

`<p> this is a text</p>`
but if I typed this:

`p!= randomText`
it would actually become a p tag, looking exactly like this:

`this is a text`

Hope it helps you :-)

You can read more about in the documentation, here: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html