# What does != do in jade/pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

How does != work in jade code below..   `!= messages()`

```
extends layout

block content
 .spacer
 .container
  .row
   .col-lg-8.col-lg-offset-2.col-md-10.col-md-offset-1
    a(class='btn btn-tiny btn-primary' href='/manage/categories/add') Create Category
    h1= title
     small
      a(href='/manage/articles')  Manage Articles
    != messages()
    table(class='table table-striped')
     tr
      th Category Title
      th
     each category, i in categories
      tr
       td #{category.title}
       td 
        a(class="btn btn-tiny btn-default" href="/manage/categories/edit/#{category._id}") Edit
```

app.js

```
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
```

Comment: It appears to be a way to output content without needing a parent tag.

Comment: Somewhat documented [here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) (_"Unescaped Buffered Code"_).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is called "interpolation".

It means that "messages()" is escaped, e.g. if you have following code:

```
var randomText = '<p> this is a <strong>text</strong></p>'
p= randomText
```

which would normally, unescaped, produce just what it is:

```
'<p> this is a <strong>text</strong></p>'
```

but if I typed this:

```
p!= randomText
```

it would actually became a p tag, looking exactly like this:

this is a **text**

Hope it helps you :-)

You can read more about in the documentation, here: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html

Comment: I think you might have it backwards, I believe the `!=` means that it is *NOT* escaped (e.g. interpret the string literally) and without it, the characters will automatically be escaped

Answer (score -2):

you should try

```
if(!messages())
 table(class='table table-striped')
```

you have to assign some value into left hand side. otherwise just validate into if condition.