# Why my pug template doesn't render properly my converted Markdown?

Tags: node.js, express, markdown, pug, mongoose-schema

I have a DB (mongodb) where I store a html format string (converted from a markdown-like input), but when I try to render it with pug, it duplicates the html...

**viewController.js**'s getArticle function is a middleware called by **'/article/:slug'** routes

```
async function getArticle(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const article = await Article.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });

    res.status(200).render('article', {
      [...],
      article /* see below to see his content */
    })

  } catch(err) {
    return next(err);
  }
}
```

**article** content:

```
{
  [...],
  "slug": "test-slug",
  "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet metus ut luctus pulvinar. Maecenas faucibus",
  "sanitizedHtml": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet metus ut luctus pulvinar. Maecenas faucibus</p>"
}
```

Then, I try to add it into my pug template named **article.pug**

```
#{article.sanitizedHtml}
```

But when I go in *localhost:8000/article/test-slug*, I got this html:

```
<
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet metus ut luctus pulvinar. Maecenas faucibus
>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet metus ut luctus pulvinar. Maecenas faucibus
>
```

I have tried to copy and paste this html format into a Pug and HTML online converter, and I don't get this error... What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this issue and was able to fix it by prepending a p-tag to you html:

p #{article.sanitizedHtml}

Comment: in your case, I get the string "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet metus ut luctus pulvinar. Maecenas faucibus</p>" in response. But, I don't want that. I want to have a p-tag where I can read "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet metus ut luctus pulvinar. Maecenas faucibus" instead of my error

Comment: can you remove the <p> tags from your html snippets before passing your response to pug for rendering?

Comment: Also, what version of pug are you using? I'm using version 2.0.4 and this seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I have found a solution. Instead of writing:
 " #{article.sanitizedHtml} ", I wrote " != #{article.sanitizedHtml} ", and it works ! see: [how != works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893264/what-does-do-in-jade-pug#:~:text=!%3D%20messages()%20extends%20layout,spacer%20.)